# argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char"

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to make a dynamic array implementation in C++ using pointers and templates so that I can accept all types. The code worked fine with `int` but using `char` gives error. I tried online other SO questions but found nothing about my scenario.
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class dynamicIntArray
{
private:
    T *arrPtr = new T[4]();
    int filledIndex = -1;
    int capacityIndex = 4;

public:
    // Get the size of array
    int size(void);

    // Check if array is empty
    bool isEmpty(void);

    // Insert a data to array
    bool insert(T n);

    // Show the array
    bool show(void);
};

template <typename T> 
int dynamicIntArray<T>::size(void)
{
return capacityIndex + 1;
}


template <typename T> 
bool dynamicIntArray<T>::insert(T n)
{
    if (filledIndex < capacityIndex)
    {
        arrPtr[++filledIndex] = n;
        return true;
    }
    else if (filledIndex == capacityIndex)
    {
        // Create new array of double size
        capacityIndex *= 2;
        T *newarrPtr = new T[capacityIndex]();

        // Copy old array
        for (int i = 0; i < capacityIndex; i++)
        {
            newarrPtr[i] = arrPtr[i];
        }

        // Add new data
        newarrPtr[++filledIndex] = n;
        arrPtr = newarrPtr;

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "ERROR";
    }
    return false;
}

template <typename T> 
bool dynamicIntArray<T>::show(void)
{
    cout << "Array elements are: ";
    for (int i = 0; i <= filledIndex; i++)
    {
        cout << arrPtr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    dynamicIntArray<char> myarray;

    myarray.insert("A");
    myarray.insert("Z");
    myarray.insert("F");
    myarray.insert("B");
    myarray.insert("K");
    myarray.insert("C");

    cout << "Size of my array is: " << myarray.size() << endl;

    myarray.show();
}
```

Error:

```
invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’
```

EDIT:
I tried using `dynamicIntArray<string> myarray;` this time it gives segmentations fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myarray.insert("A");` … `"A"` is a `const char[]`, but insert expects `char`. You can change this to `myarray.insert('A')`

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. Can you see the edit at the end of my question, if you can solve that then I can accept this answer.

Comment: This is a different question that deserves a different post, then ;)

Comment: @R.Gurung please one question per question. If you have a follow up question you can ask a new question. THis answer does answer your original question.

Answer (score 4):

For starters the code has several bugs.

For example the function `size` returns an invalid value.

```
template <typename T> 
int dynamicIntArray<T>::size(void)
{
return capacityIndex + 1;
}
```

Initially the array is allocated with 4 elements

```
T *arrPtr = new T[4]();
int capacityIndex = 4;
```

but the function returns 5 ( `capacityIndex + 1` ).

In the function `insert` there are accesses to the memory beyond the allocated array. For example when filledIndex is euql to `capacityIndex - 1`  then in this if statement

```
if (filledIndex < capacityIndex)
{
    arrPtr[++filledIndex] = n;
    return true;
}
```

the value `n` is written at the position equal to `capacityIndex` while the valid range of indices is `[0, capacityIndex)`.

In this code snippet

```
    capacityIndex *= 2;
    T *newarrPtr = new T[capacityIndex]();

    // Copy old array
    for (int i = 0; i < capacityIndex; i++)
    {
        newarrPtr[i] = arrPtr[i];
    }
```

the data member  `capacityIndex` was increased

```
    capacityIndex *= 2;
```

However you are using this new value in the for loop

```
    for (int i = 0; i < capacityIndex; i++)
    {
        newarrPtr[i] = arrPtr[i];
    }
```

to copy non-existent elements of the array pointed to by `arrPtr`.

As for the compiler error then in statements like this

```
myarray.insert("A");
```

you are using string literals. For example the string literal `"A"` has the type `const char[2]` that in the argument expression is converted to the type `const char *`.

This pointer you are trying to assign to an object of the type `char` that is to the object of the allocated dynamically array with the element type `char`.

You should write like

```
myarray.insert( 'A' );
```

That is instead of a string literal you have to use a character literal that has the type `char` - the type of the type template argument.